# jQuery validate next 3 form fields onkeyup when previous formfield is filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I have a form, when submit is pressed and formfield `propBacklink` has a value, the following 3 fields (X, Y, Z) are validated too. This is regardless of their values, as they are readonly. An Ajax call returns if they are true or false based on the variables in their Ajax calls.

My problem is, how can I force the validation of fields (X, Y, Z) onkeyup of formfield `propBacklink`?

```html
propBacklink: {
    required: false,
    url: true,
    remote: {
 url: "backlinkInDB.php",
 type: "post"
    },
    rules: {
 CheckNextFields: true
    }
},

$.validator.addMethod("CheckNextFields", function( value ) {

 this.element($("[name='X']")).validate();
 this.element($("[name='Y']")).validate();
 this.element($("[name='Z']")).validate();

});
```

Comment: You can't run a Code Snippet if the code is missing.  In other words, the JavaScript is useless without the relevant HTML.  Edited to remove snippet.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  By default, validation is also triggered on `keyup` and on `focusout`.  Are you asking about how to trigger validation based on some other event(s)?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Hope this addition explains better: Indeed, the current form field with focus is validated onkeyup. But i also want fields X,Y,Z to be validated onkeyup of form filed A.

Comment: I have some ideas but you're going to need to show your code attempt.   So instead of following the advice of my first comment and adding the relevant HTML, you removed all code?  Just dumping a functional request with nothing else does not make a good question.  See:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Since your OP contains no code whatsoever, my answer will not contain code...

> how can I force the validation of fields (X, Y, Z) `onkeyup`  of formfield `propBacklink`?

By default, the plugin evaluates the entire form on the `click` of submit, and each field individually on `keyup` and on `focusout` *(on `click` for `radio`, `checkbox`, and `select`.)*

Since you want to evaluate a group of fields when the `propBacklink` field is triggered, you'll need to write a new method (rule) for `propBacklink` using [the `.addMethod()` method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/).

- Within this custom function, you can trigger validation on any element using `this.element()`.

  ```
  this.element(element); // the field being evaluated by the custom method: propBacklink
  this.element($('[name="X"]')); // field with name="X"
  ```
- Only assign or declare this new rule to one field, `propBacklink`.  `X`, `Y`, and `Z` will be validated as per the `this.element()` contained within the function of your new custom rule.
- Pay attention to the [hundreds of examples posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery-validate%5D%20addmethod) as well as the [documentation within the tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info).

---

**EDIT**:

I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish with this scheme of triggering validation on `readonly` fields that the user cannot directly control.

The following will check to see if `X`, `Y`, and `Z` are valid, and return an error if any of them fail validation.

```
$.validator.addMethod("CheckNextFields", function(value, element) {

    return this.optional(element) || (this.element($("[name='X']")) && this.element($("[name='Y']")) && this.element($("[name='Z']")));

}, "X, Y, and Z are not valid.");
```

*(Of course, you'll also need to assign some validation rules to `X`, `Y`, and `Z` if you want to validate them.  Otherwise, what would you trigger?)*

The format of your rules object is a little messed up too.  You are supposed to put the rules inside of the `rules` object.  They are comprised of key:value pairs of the field name and the list of rules for each.

```
$('#yourform').validate({
    rules: {
        propBacklink: {
            // rules for propBacklink
            required: false,  // <- superfluous (default)
            url: true,
            remote: {
                url: "backlinkInDB.php",
                type: "post"
            },
            CheckNextFields: true
        },
        X: {
            // rules for X
        },
        Y: {
            // rules for Y
        },
        Z: {
            // rules for Z
        },
        ....
    },
    ....
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice! After hours of searching and playing around I came up with the code above, but that doesn't work yet unfortunately. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @Peps, still not clear on what you're doing, but I edited my answer to show you what your custom method should look like.